# How can I make libjpeg available to python2.5?

Tags: 11.04, python, libraries, image-processing

I am running Ubuntu 11.04. Along with python 2.7 I have also 2.6 and 2.5. I am using 2.5 version to work and deploy my applications on App Engine. I have installed PIL (Python Image library) but despite I have all the dependencies covered it informs me that it cannot support jpeg and the rest of formats. How can I make the libjpeg-dev available to my custom python installation?

Comment: I managed to make them available by adding their path to ./configure script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PIL setup.py file if you are trying to install with easy_install the ./configure script is not available. If you open the setup.py in the first lines somewhere are the paths for Jpeg support zlib support etc. I set their values according to my paths of the installed libraries. So the setup.py looks like this before executing it:

```
 37 JPEG_ROOT = "/usr/lib"
 38 ZLIB_ROOT = "/usr/lib/zlib/lib"
 39 TIFF_ROOT = None
 40 FREETYPE_ROOT = "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/"
```

I have manually installed zlib under `/usr/lib/zlib` to serve my needs.

The selftest.py of PIL will recognize the available libraries. Recompile PIL and everything is set!

Answer (score 0):

I found it simpler/nicer to add symlinks to the non-standard Ubuntu library locations:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

(your `.so` locations may vary; try `locate libjpeg.so` etc to find them if necessary)

Reinstalling PIL after fixing these worked fine for me.

-- also simpler for virtualenv installations where setup.py isn't readily editable